# VBA Conditional Formatting - add an Expression

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I have the following conditions when I create a worksheet via vba, the first two work fine in that if the cell date is two days prior to today's date then it turns orange or if the cell date is due/overdue the cell turns red, what doesn't work at all is the last condition, it is simply ignored. The condition I would like is if the cell P2 is not blank it turns cell O2 green.  I have no idea what I am doing wrong, any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
    Set MyRange = Range("o2:o" & J)
    Set MyRange1 = Range("P2:P" & J)

    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($O2>TODAY(),$O2<= 
    (TODAY()+2))"
    MyRange.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 153, 51)

    MyRange.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlLessEqual, _
    Formula1:="=NOW()"
    MyRange.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)

   MyRange1.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=P2<>"""
   MyRange.FormatConditions(3).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 153, 0)
```

Comment: You assign the formula to `MyRange1` but set the color to `MyRange` - is that a typo?

Comment: No not a typo cell O2 is the date due and cell P2 signifies if this has been actioned with a dropdown of "Yes".  So if "Yes" is selected in cell P2 then Cell O2 (date) goes green

Comment: Your last line looks to be working on the MyRange, not MyRange1.  You are adding a 3rd color but you only have 2 conditions, this should be `MyRange1.FormatConditions(1).` i believe is what @FunThomas is getting at

Comment: In that case, the third FormatCondition needs to be assigned also to `MyRange`. You need to assign the FormatCondition to the cell to be formatted, not to the cell that holds the value you are checking.

Comment: `Formula1:="=P2<>"""` should be `Formula1:="=P2<>"""""`